# java: Why does not both threads execute in parallel

Tags: java, multithreading, loops, for-loop, context-switching

I am trying to understand the intrinsic locks in java. I have a program where I start 2 threads which will loop thru and call synchronized methods on a same object. I expect that both threads to execute things in parallel but Looks like it executes in sequence.

If I introduce a sleep in the loop then they execute in random order [as i expected]

```
public class Synchronized {

    private int valueM;

    public Synchronized( int value) {
        valueM = value;
    }

    synchronized
    public void one() throws InterruptedException
    {
        System.out.println("Object[" + valueM + "] executing one");
        Thread.sleep(100); //For case 2: comment it out
        System.out.println("Object[" + valueM + "] completed one");
    }

    synchronized
    public void two() throws InterruptedException
    {
        System.out.println("Object[" + valueM + "] executing two");
        Thread.sleep(100); //For case 2: comment it out
        System.out.println("Object[" + valueM + "] completed two");
    }

}
```

Test Code:

```
@org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
    void test_sync() throws InterruptedException
    {
        Synchronized obj = new Synchronized(1);

        Runnable task_one = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                for (int i=0 ; i<10; i++)
                {
                    try {
                        obj.one();
                        //Thread.sleep(100); //For case 2: uncomment it out
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        Runnable task_two = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                for (int i=0 ; i<10; i++)
                {
                    try {
                        obj.two();
                        //Thread.sleep(100); //For case 2: uncomment it out
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        Thread t1 = new Thread(task_one);
        Thread t2 = new Thread(task_two);

        t1.start();
        t2.start();

        t1.join();
        t2.join();
    }
```

Output:

```
Case 1: output:
Object[1] executing one
Object[1] completed one
...10times
Object[1] executing two
Object[1] completed two
...10times

Case 2: output: random order
Object[1] executing one
Object[1] completed one
Object[1] executing two
Object[1] completed two
...
```

UPDATE:
The original issue is fixed.. Looks like it is random even in case 1 also, but I see it only when I load with more iterations (30K)..

So thread switching happens much less in a for loop with no sleeps? Is it something special to Java-JVM which tries to have for-loop to execute it as a "kind-of" atomic (not fully but as much as possible?) ?

Comment: What if you make the loops bigger? e.g. 30k or more iterations?

Comment: @MargaretBloom I suspected it so, tried with 1000, let me do with 30K

Comment: @SamDaniel I copied your code and ran it as is: It was not in order. It showed 9 times 1, 10 time 2, 1 time 1. I would think that without a sleep the methods are so quick that the time between the to `run()` calls is enough for the first thread to finish, or at least get most of its work done, before the second one even starts.

Comment: your case 1 output is random, you should re-run many times to check

Comment: @MargaretBloom that did the trick. 1000 was not enough.. when I looped for 30000, then I started seeing random..

Comment: I would think that there is some optimization at work that tries to avoid to much overhead by switching threads too frequently. With longer work times (in the `run` method), you might see more switches. I found [this article about lock contention and context switching](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/threads/context_switch.shtml) quite interesting.

Answer (score 1):

The `intrinsic` lock (`synchronized` keyword) is considered "unfair" which means there's no guarantee that the acquisition rate of the lock will be the same among competing threads.

It's a known fact that **the thread that release the lock is usually more likely to acquire it again** causing the problem you are experiencing.

If you want your thread to have similar acquisition likelihood (fairness) you can use an explicit lock like the [ReentrantLock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html) making sure to use the optional `boolean` parameter setting it to true

```
ReentrantLock(boolean fair)
```

Then you can use it this way

```
class X {
  private final ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock(true);

  public void m() {
    lock.lock(); 
    try {
      // method body
    } finally {
     lock.unlock()
   }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have marked methods `one` and `two` as `synchronized`. This means that before a thread can enter any of them, it must acquire a lock on `obj`. A thread can not acquire a lock if another thread is holding it. When the thread exits `one` / `two`, the lock is released and both threads compete for it again. Sometimes the first thread succeeds, sometimes the second - this is why you are seeing random order of calls, but never intermixed.

So this is by design. Effectively, you have told JVM that you **don't** want both threads to run at the same time.

Comment: I understand the threading concept. The question is why it is not random in the first case.

Comment: The ordering is not deterministic. As the threads compete, either might get the lock the next time. There is no guarantee of any kind. The actual outcome might depend on JVM implementation, CPU scheduling algorithm, or for the lack of better example, weather. So even if you see a sequence, is in fact still a random (more precisely: unpredictable) order.

Answer (score 0):

Lets try to understand your question and then try to see the expected result.

1. There are 2 methods which are `synchronized` on same object (current object of type `Synchronized`).
2. There are 2 threads. Each thread in its path of execution tries to invoke one of the synchronized method multiple times.
3. There are two cases, case 1 do not have `sleep` method invoked on the thread and case 2 has `sleep` method invoked on the currently executing thread.

Now Starting with point number 3. `sleep` does not release the lock. Its the `wait` method invoked on the object upon which lock has been aquired which releases the lock for other threads. So in your case basically sleep just makes the execution slow and nothing else.

The thread scheduler decides the order of execution of threads and also the processor cycle sharing. The  does not gurantee any order and niether it gurantees any randomness, it simply may or may not be random.

Now when as I said `sleep` does not releases the lock, then how we get random order of execution sometimes ? The answer is : as soon as the execution of one of the synchronized method is over by one of the two threads , lock is released and thread scheduler decides which thread to give next chance for execution.

Answer (score 0):

Thread#start is a very slow method in relative terms.  Counting to 10 (or counting to 1,000) does not take a computer very long.  The first thread is done counting long before the operating system has done the work for the second thread to actually execute.  If you want to actually start two threads "at the same time" you need to use a latch.

Your test is also confounded by the fact that depending on your execution environment the system console writer may itself be a synchronized contested resource (or conversely it may not be guaranteed to flush and write in a point-in-time consistent way with the order threads accessed it.)  Trying to use System.out.println to debug concurrency issues has caused many people much trouble over the years because the pause to acquire the console writer usually hides their memory consistency error.

```
public static CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

public static class Thing implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            latch.await();
            //doStuff
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

        }
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Thing thing1 = new Thing();
    Thing thing2 = new Thing();
    new Thread(thing1).start();
    new Thread(thing2).start();
    latch.countDown();
}
```